# Matrix associated with a projection mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, projection

From S.L Linear Algebra:

> Find the matrix associated with the following linear maps. The vectors
>   are written horizontally with a transpose sign for typographical
>   reasons.
>   (a) $F:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $F\left ((x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)^T \right)=(x_1, x_2)^T$ (the projection)

## Solution Attempt

I will use **Theorem 2.1** from the book:

> Let $L: K^n \rightarrow K^m$ be a linear map. Then there exists a
>   unique matrix $A$ such that $L = L_A$.

Hence, for all $X$ we have $L(X)=AX$.

In this case, some $A$ is the matrix associated with linear map $F$ such that:

$$F(X^T)=AX^T$$
$$F\left ((x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)^T \right)=A\left ((x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)^T \right)$$
$$AX^T=A\left ((x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)^T \right)=(x_1, x_2)^T$$

Solving for $A$:

$$A=\left ((x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)^T \right)^{-1}(x_1, x_2)^T$$

Now this makes **no sense**, because $X$ must be non-degenerate square matrix in order to be invertible, but $X$ is just a vector with cardinality (dimension) $4$.

Perhaps I could invert $A$ (then I would have to show that $F$ is injective with trivial kernel), but I don't see any point of doing this.

Is $A$ truly a matrix associated with $F$? If not, how to find $A$ if it is a matrix that is truly associated with $F$?

---

**P.S**

I also found this in the book:

> Let $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be the projection, in
>   other words the mapping such that $F(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_1, x_2)$.
>   Then the matrix associated with $F$ is:
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  & 0 \\   0&1   & 0  \end{pmatrix}$$

I don't know how was it exactly calculated, but the matrix above contains standard basis vectors only, which I believe must mean something.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: The columns of the matrix are the images of the basis vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, the Vector Space of Matrices $\mathscr{M}_{mn}(\mathbb{R}^4)$ is not abelian under matrix product! *It is a fundamental error to change sides of a matrix by "inverting it" in an equation.*

And keep in mind: you can see obviously that $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be extended so to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$. It is why they indicated that the image was a **projection** in fact.

Now let's calculate:

The first intuition is to write down what your matrix operations look like; to find out if the product is well-defined somehow: this will eliminate some big issues in your thoughts.

$$ F(\left (
\begin{matrix}
 x_1 \\ 
 x_2 \\
 x_3 \\
 x_4 
\end{matrix}
\right )
)=\left (
\begin{matrix}
 x_1 \\ 
 x_2 
\end{matrix}
\right )
 $$

ie.

$$ \left (
\begin{matrix}
 a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\ 
 a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}
\end{matrix}
\right )
.\left (
\begin{matrix}
 x_1 \\ 
 x_2 \\
 x_3 \\
 x_4 
\end{matrix}
\right )
=\left (
\begin{matrix}
 x_1 \\ 
 x_2 
\end{matrix}
\right )
 $$

when we introduce the Matrix of elements $(a_{ij})$ as the Matrix associated to the linear transformation. We must have a $2x4$ matrix for this transformation.

When you do the calculations, you'll find:

$$ \begin{cases}
 a_{11}x_{1} + a_{12}x_{2} + a_{13}x_{3} + a_{14}x_{4} = x_1 \\ 
 a_{21}x_{1} + a_{22}x_{2} + a_{23}x_{3} + a_{24}x_{4} = x_2
\end{cases} $$

ie.

$$ \begin{cases}
 (a_{11}-1)x_{1} + a_{12}x_{2} + a_{13}x_{3} + a_{14}x_{4} = 0 \\ 
 a_{21}x_{1} + (a_{22}-1)x_{2} + a_{23}x_{3} + a_{24}x_{4} = 0
\end{cases} $$

But as we're looking for a basis, we know it must be linearly independent **(within row vctors).** So that, we know, every coefficients are zero, with $(a_{11}-1)=0$ and $(a_{22}-1)=0$ so that we have $a_{11}=1$ and $a_{22}=1$, over row vectors.

Thus, we conclude that one basis for this linear transformation in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is:

$$
\left (
\begin{matrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\end{matrix}
\right )$$

Comment: Wow that makes a lot of sense. Thank you! My lack of familiarity with matrices is the primary reason for my ignorance. Also, you have mentioned that linear transformation is an isomorphism, that means that it is bijective and hence kernel under $F$ is trivial, correct?

Comment: I'm glad you see more clearly. But attention: I didn't say that every linear transformation is isomorphism. Indeed, here it is surjective because we have a *projection* of a vector of $\mathbb{R}^4$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$. I wanted you to see the reverse: We could have **extended** the image by null vectors to have an isomorphism. So that you can **visualize** the fact that **matrix associated needn't to be square, but only well-defined.**

Comment: Yes, of course. I just wanted to further discover properties of only linear transformations that are defined by projection.  Thank you for the help!